# Change the tab color on clicking the tab C# Winforms Infragistics

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, infragistics, .net-4.8

The tab color is not changing on click of the selected tab. But it is changing when I select another tab.
Let's say there are two tabs A and B. On click of Tab A, it is not changing. But when I click Tab B, it is changing Tab A color.

HomeDesigner.cs

```
public Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTabControl.UltraTabControl homeTabControl;
this.homeTabControl.SelectedTabChanging += new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTabControl.SelectedTabChangingEventHandler(this.homeTabControl_SelectedTabChanging);
this.homeTabControl.SelectedTabChanged += new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTabControl.SelectedTabChangedEventHandler(this.homeTabControl_SelectedTabChanged);
```

Home.cs

```
private async void homeTabControl_SelectedTabChanged(object sender, SelectedTabChangedEventArgs e)
{
int count = 1;
    if (e.Tab.Key == "DecorDesign")
    {
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    e.Tab.Appearance.ForeColor = Color.White;
                    e.Tab.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    e.Tab.Appearance.BackColor2 = Color.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Tab.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
    }
}


private void homeTabControl_SelectedTabChanging(object sender, SelectedTabChangingEventArgs e)
{
int count = 1;
    if (e.Tab.Key == "DecorDesign")
    {
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    e.Tab.Appearance.ForeColor = Color.White;
                    e.Tab.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    e.Tab.Appearance.BackColor2 = Color.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Tab.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }
    }
}
```

I tried giving the color change logic in homeTabControl_SelectedTabChanged and homeTabControl_SelectedTabChanging. The tab is not changing to Red color on the click of 'HomeDecor' tab. But it is changing to Red, when I click on any other tab.

How to change the tab color and see the color change upon clicking it

Comment: If I still remember well there are two other appearance settings to consider here. The ActiveAppearance and the SelectedAppearance.  The one you are changing is the "normal" appearance settings

Comment: ActiveApperance worked. Thank you very much @Steve.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `ActiveAppearance` setting worked.